# gmapping: disable TF publishing

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use an `ukf_robot_localization` to fuse the pose (map -> odom) from gmapping, AMCL and another not continuous pose source (not a GPS).

My problem is that the gmapping node broadcasts the "map -> odom" transform that should instead be broadcasted only by the UKF filter.

I searched about how to inhibit the gmapping node from broadcasting the TF, but I have not found the relative parameter.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314604/gmapping:-disable-tf-publishing/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2019-02-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [source code](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/5a707e079364ab9f5349c72310f31bfed4a6c834/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L339-L348), setting the `transform_publish_period` to `0` inhibits publishing of the transform.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2019-02-04**:
Thank you @mgruhler, you are right.

I missed that line of code, I was concentrating on the [publishTransform](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L785-L791) function.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-04**:
Updated the parameter documentation on the wiki in [wiki/gmapping?action=diff&rev1=127&rev2=128](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping?action=diff&rev1=127&rev2=128).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-02-04**:
thx @gvdhoorn for the edit.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2019-02-04**:
@gvdhoorn I think that publishing a `pose_with_covariance` message should be useful to be fused in a kalman filter with the pose published by AMCL.

Normally only one of Gmapping and AMCL should work... but if you do not have a map it is not bad to run both and fuse their results...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-04**:
I'm not sure I understand your comment.

I'm not the author nor the maintainer of `gmapping`. I merely updated the wiki page to document that `transform_publish_period==0` means: no transforms published.